# DATABASE_URL is null in Heroku dyno

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to deploy my Django application to Heroku and make separate configuration for local and heroku deployments. I currently have this:

```
if 'DATABASE_URL' in os.environ:
    import dj_database_url
    DATABASES = {
        'default': dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }
```

Method `main` basically creates an instance of Selenium (geckodriver) and scrapes something off a web page. However, if I try to run it locally using statement:

```
heroku ps:exec
```

And then running:

```
python3 -c 'from scraper.common import main; main()'
```

It prints:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: scraper_listing
```

Because it was still using SQLite database. I then connected to dyno the same way and tried:

```
python3 -c 'import os; os.environ'
```

and:

```
echo $DATABASE_URL
```

And the output is not showing DATABASE_URL variable. Can somebody please help me?

Edit: Mentioned env var is set in Heroku:

[image: DATABASE_URL in heroku]

And if I run command `heroku config` I can also see it.

Comment: Visit the heroku dashboard, go to your App, then settings and look under environment variables if `DATABASE_URL` was set there.

Comment: Yes, it is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the problem is that `heroku ps:exec` does not use postgresql and uses sqlite. I dont know why the documentation says that it connects to existing dyno. It does not work for me.

Use `heroku run bash`